# Laravel: artisan explination

Tags: php, laravel-4

I'm new to laravel and I'm trying to understand some of the stuff that the artisan command line tool is doing but I can't seem to find a clear explanation.

When I type in:

```
php artisan help view:publish
```

It gives me the syntax and different flags I can throw, but no explanation of what the command actually does.

When I look on laravel's website to read the [documentation on the artisan tool](http://laravel.com/docs/artisan) I get an incredibly brief explanation of how to use the tool but nothing on any of it's commands and the [development section of the docs](http://laravel.com/docs/commands) show's how to build command but not what they do.

I've searched around online and I've not found anything that helps. I'm sure I'm wearing my frustration glasses and I'm missing some obvious sources, but it's hard to take those glasses off sometimes.

Does anyone know where I can find manual so I can rtf out of it??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the aritsan command: `$ php artisan list`

It will give you a synopsis of all of the built-in (and custom-made) commands.  In the case of view:publish, this is what it reports:

```
view   
  view:publish   Publish a package's views to the application
```

Comment: I guess I'm looking for a bit more detail on it's brief explanations. When it says "Publish a package's views to the application" what does that actually mean? I did it and it did not put any of the view into the view folder, so where did they go?